# How to pass prop to header component in layout, based on pages' data in Nuxt 3

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

What I'm trying to achieve is to have a header component which changes background color based on the page it's on. So for example when it's on page A and C it should have a transparent header while on page B and D it should have a white background header.

I'm not sure what's the best way to do this.Using different layouts for only one prop or giving each page a body class especially for this feels like too much.

```
<!-- default.vue -->
<template>
    <div>
        <Header isLight />
        <slot />
        <Footer />
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
    const isLight = computed(() => (something ? true : false));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [watcher](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#watch) on the route, and update `isLight` based on whatever the current route name or path currently is.

```js
<script setup>
const isLight = ref(false);
const route = useRoute();

watch(
  () => route.name,
  newRoute => {
    if (newRoute === 'PageA' || newRoute === 'PageC' ) {
      isLight.value = true;
    } else {
      isLight.value = false;
    }
  },
  {
    immediate: true
  }
);
</script>
```

Comment: this should should work. I'd just change the line `if (newRoute === 'PageA' || newRoute === 'PageC' )` to be more flexible by adding pages in an Array and use includes like this `if ( ['PageA', 'PageB'].includes(newRoute) )`

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to approach this a bit more dynamic. Ideally I'd have a CMS with for each page a header setting to show the dark or light header on that specific page. Any ideas?